# React-Native: Function is not being triggered after timer finishes running

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, clearinterval

I created a timer that works like this:

```
    const targetTime = new Date(props.targetDate).getTime();
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(Date.now());

    const timeBetween = targetTime - currentTime;

    const days = Math.floor(timeBetween / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((timeBetween % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((timeBetween % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((timeBetween % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (timeBetween < 0) { props.onTimerFinish() }
            setCurrentTime(Date.now());
        }, 1000);
        return () => { clearInterval(interval) };
    }, []);
```

Then I have my UI that are 4 `View`'s displaying days, hours, min, sec.

The `onTimerFinish` is a Void Function i.e. `() => void`. I'm checking `if (timeBetween < 0)` at ever interval so that the moment it goes to negative I'll know the time is up and I want to trigger the `onTimerFinish` which is in the parent component of the timer as:

```
const testDate1 = '2022-11-15T09:30:00.000Z';

<MyCountdownTimer targetDate ={testDate1} onTimerFinish={() => {
     console.log("Hello");
}} />
```

After the timer runs out it doesn't call `onTimerFinish`. I want to refresh the parent component upon finishing the timer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, replace `if (timeBetween < 0) { props.onTimerFinish() }` to `if (targetTime - currentTime < 0) { props.onTimerFinish() }` may be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't work. The timer goes to zero and the console.log inside `onTimerFinish` doesn't gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **clear the interval when the timer reaches 0**.

```
const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = React.useState(Date.now());

const timeBetween = React.useMemo(() => targetTime - currentTime, [currentTime]);

const days = Math.floor(timeBetween / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
const hours = Math.floor(
(timeBetween % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
);
const minutes = Math.floor((timeBetween % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
const seconds = Math.floor((timeBetween % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

React.useEffect(() => {
    timer = setInterval(function () { // declare timer as globally
        setCurrentTime(Date.now());
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timer) {
        if (timeBetween <= 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            alert("Timer finish");
        }
    }
}, [timeBetween]);
```

Comment: It works but I have a question, why does it show multiple `alert("Timer finish")`? As I get around 5-6 alerts when the timer was finished.